# TypeORM: Many-to-many custom column names

Tags: typescript, typeorm

Given the following two **TypeORM** entities that have a **@ManyToMany** relationship:

```js
@Entity({ name: 'products' })
export class ProductEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(type => CategoryEntity, { eager: true })
  @JoinTable({ name: 'products_categories' })
  categories: CategoryEntity[];
}
```

```js
@Entity({ name: 'categories' })
export class CategoryEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn({ length: 40 })
  code: string;
}
```

As a result I get created a table called `"products_categories"` with the following column names:

- `productsId`
- `categoriesCode`

Is there a way of giving these two columns custom names? I would like to rename them as follows:

- `productsId` -> `productId`
- `categoriesCode` -> `categoryCode`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Solved it by extending the options object given to `@JoinTable`, which I missed from the [TypeORM docs](https://typeorm.io/#/relations/jointable-options):

```
@ManyToMany(type => CategoryEntity, { eager: true })
@JoinTable({
    name: "products_categories",
    joinColumn: {
        name: "product",
        referencedColumnName: "id"
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
        name: "category",
        referencedColumnName: "id"
    }
})
categories: CategoryEntity[];
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much for this ! You made my day !