# How can I define many to many columns with NestJS and TypeORM?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm new to NestJS/TypeORM so apologies and forgiveness please.

I have a many to many relationship created; my table is created automatically with the correct columns.

I have a location that can have many users, and a user can have many locations.

My route looks like this:

```js
http://localhost:3000/locations/:location-id/users
```

My `location.entity.ts` looks like this:

```js
@ManyToMany(type => User, user => user.locations, { eager: true })
  @JoinTable()
  users: User[];
```

My `user.entity.ts` looks like this:

```js
@ManyToMany(type => Location, location => location.users, { eager: false })
  locations: Location[];
```

`location_users_user` table is getting generated with these columns:

```js
locationId | userId
```

So far, everything looks great! When I send a `GET` request to my route using Postman, I am seeing this error in the console:

```
column location_users_user.locationid does not exist
```

I see that `locationid` is what it's looking for, when my column name is `locationId`. Is there somewhere I need to set the case of the column names?

I have also worked through [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58240290/typeorm-many-to-many-custom-column-names) to set additional params in the `JoinTable` decorator.

That leaves me with this:

```js
// location.entitiy.ts
@ManyToMany(type => User, user => user.locations, { eager: true })
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'location_user',
    joinColumn: {
      name: 'locationId',
      referencedColumnName: 'id',
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: 'userId',
      referencedColumnName: 'id',
    },
  })
  users: User[];
```

However, I'm still getting this error:

```
column location_users_user.locationid does not exist
```

I don't think I'm setting the correct `Join` or something. I only have that decorator on my location entity.

Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

I have updated my `user.repository.ts` file as follows:

```js
async getLocationUsers(locationId: number): Promise<User[]> {
    const query = this.createQueryBuilder('location_user')
      .where('location_user.locationId = :locationId', { locationId });
```

The error still thinks I am looking for a `locationid` column. I've changed it to `foo` to just see if I was even in the correct spot and I am. I'm not sure why it's missing the case of `locationId`.

**EDIT2**

I've found that it could be a possible Postgres thing? Using double quotes, I'm now seeing the correct table/column name in my error:

```js
const query = this.createQueryBuilder('location_user')
      .where('location_user."locationId" = :locationId', { locationId });
```

Results in: `column location_user.locationId does not exist` 
Which is still odd, because that table does exist and so does the column.

**Edit**

Here is the `location.entity.ts` file:

```js
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(type => User, user => user.locations, { eager: true })
  @JoinTable()
  users: User[];
```

Here is the `user.entity.ts` file:

```js
 @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
 id: number;

 @Column()
 email: string;

 @ManyToMany(type => Location, location => location.users, { eager: false })
 locations: Location[];
```

I'm able to see the users' relationship when I get a specific location, so I know that's working properly. I am trying to just get all users that belong to the location; here is what my `user.repository.ts` file looks like:

```js
async getLocationUsers(locationId: number): Promise<User[]> {
    const query = this.createQueryBuilder('user')
      .where('location_users_user."locationId" = :locationId', { locationId });
});

    try {
      return await query.getMany();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('error: ', e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you please add full code of the two entities?

Comment: Hi @yash I've just updated my question at the bottom to include the relationships and my repository method. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just checked some of my own code using `@ManyToMany`, the only 2 differences I can spot are the following:

### 1st Best bet

In my repository, when calling TypeOrm's `createQueryBuilder` method with a joined column, two things differ:

1. I use a `leftJoin` (might be another one depending on your use case logic and DB design) to retrieve the linked table
2. There is no double quote on the FK field you want to filter the results

Your `getLocationUsers` method's code in `user.repository.ts` would result in the following:

```js
async getLocationUsers(locationId: number): Promise<User[]> {
    const query = this.createQueryBuilder('user')
      .leftJoin('user.locations', 'location')
      .where('location.id = :locationId', { locationId });
});

    try {
      return await query.getMany();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('error: ', e);
    }
  }
```

### 2nd just in case 1st one doesn't solve your problem

```js
@ManyToMany(type => Location, location => location.users, { eager: false })
```

while I'm using

```js
@ManyToMany(() => Location, (location) => location.users, { eager: false })
```

Would this difference (don't use `type =>` but `() =>`) change anything ? I honestly don't think so, might be some syntax sugar (or not - to be confirmed, this is only assumption)

Hope it helps, let me know :)

Comment: This is really interesting. I had to use the double quote otherwise I wasn't getting the correct case for `locationId`. It seems this was the part that I was clearly not doing correctly: `.leftJoin('user.locations', 'location')`.
Thank you so much for your time. It helped get me back on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late to a party but here's an i[nteresting article](https://blog.continium-labs.com/many-to-many-relations-with-typeorm-and-nestjs/) on the subject.