# One way one to many relation

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a `Recipe` and a `Tag` model. Currently, the recipe contains an array of id's belonging to `Tag`:

```
    @Entity()
    export class Recipe extends BaseEntity {
      @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
      public id!: string;
    
      @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
      public title!: string;
    
      @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
      public description!: string;
    
      @Column({ type: 'simple-array', nullable: true })
      public tags: string[];

    }

@Entity()
export class Tag extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  public id!: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
  public name!: string;
}
```

However, I am currently not making use of the relational capabilities of TypeORM. I was wondering though, how would i go about doing this? Since the relation only works one way, i.e. the one Recipe having many Tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I believe by default, you must declare both ways--even if you only intend to use a single direction of the relationship.

For example, you need to declare that a `Recipe` has many `Tags` you also have to set up the `Tag` to `Recipe` relationship even if you aren't going to use it.

Given your example, you'll need to set up a one:many and a many:one relationship.

Since `Recipe` will "own" the tags, it will have the one:many:

```
// recipe.entity.ts

@OneToMany(() => Tag, (tag) => tag.recipe)
tags: Tag[];
```

Then the inverse will look like this:

```
// tag.entity.ts

@ManyToOne(() => Recipe, (recipe) => recipe.tags)
@JoinColumn({
    name: 'recipeId',
})
recipe: Recipe;
```

If you're considering having many recipes own the same tag, you may need to consider [using a many:many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63078720/how-can-i-define-many-to-many-columns-with-nestjs-and-typeorm)

**EDIT**

I suppose you could technically store an array of id's in a column to represent tags for any given recipe. The question here is, what happens if you decide you need further info on any given tag?

IMO, (and it's just that so take all of this with a grain of salt). You are bending your recipe table to also store relationship info.

I have found it to be more helpful to keep my "buckets" (tables) as specific as possible. That'd leave us with:

```
recipes | tags | recipes_tags
-----------------------------
```

That way my `recipes` table just has recipes & that's it. "Just give me all recipes...". Tags is the same, "just show me all tags"

The two things are completely different entities. By setting up a `ManyToMany` relationship, we're telling TypeORM that these two columns are related--without "muddying" either of their underlying data.

You can add/remove columns on the pivot table should you decide you want more info about the relationship. At that point, you'd still be working with the relationship, not a tag or recipe so your data would still be nice & lean!

Another example from one of my own use cases...

I have an `Activity` and a `Resource` any given resource can have one or more `Activities`. (activities = tags/ resources = recipes)

```
// activity.entity.ts

...
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

@Column()
name: string;

...

@ManyToMany((type) => Resource, (resource) => resource.activities)
resources: Resource[];
```

```
// resource.entity.ts

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
id: string;

@Column()
name: string;

...

@JoinTable()
@ManyToMany((type) => Activity, (activity) => activity.resources)
activities: Activity[];
```

The above generates a `resources_activities_activities` table.
Within that table is:

```
resourceId | activityId
------------------------
```

I could add additional columns here as well. `createdBy` or `status` or something else that is specific to the *relationship*. Each entry in this table has a relationship back to the activity *and* the resource--which is great!

I realize we've gone outside the scope of your original question, but I think this is a pretty small step outside, for a potential big win later on.

When I make a request to get a resource: `example.com/resources/123` I get something like this back:

```
"id": "123"
...
"activities": [
    {
        "id": "f79ce066-75ba-43bb-bf17-9e60efa65e25",
        "name": "Foo",
        "description": "This is what Foo is.",
        "createdAt": "xxxx-xx-xxxxx:xx:xx.xxx",
        "updatedAt": "xxxx-xx-xxxxx:xx:xx.xxx"
    }
]
...
```

Likewise, any time I get an activity, I also get back any resources that are related to it. In my front-end I can then easily do something like `resource.activities`.

Comment: Got it Damon, but the problem here would be the recipeId column right, I don't want a recipeId column in my Tag table

Comment: Right on - check out my link to the many:many relationship. That'll give you another table that will consist of a `recipeId` and a `tagId`.  I think that might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Wondering though, is it worth it to add a completely new table, or could i just store the ID's as strings when creating a Recipe, and then query them later on..

Comment: Great question! I've updated my answer to give a bit more breathing room vs. comments.

Comment: Appreciate the extended info! Your reasoning makes 100% sense, I'll go the linking table route!